# Difference between $req->param & $req->input('param')

Tags: laravel

I am new in Laravel, so maybe this is a dumb question.

```
    $param = $req->input('param');
    $param = $req->param;
```

Both of them show the same result. The first one is what i learn from most site in internet. Is there any difference between them? Which one is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both **$req->input('param')** and **$req->param** are used to retrieve input data from the request.

**$req->input('param')** is more explicit and indicates that you are specifically retrieving a value from the input. It also allows you to specify a default value to be returned if the parameter is not found like this

```
$param = $req->input('param', 'default');
```

This second argument will be returned if the parameter is not found in the request.

**$req->param**
is more concise and can be used as a shortcut for retrieving a parameter from the request and does not allow you to specify a default value.

There is no functional difference between the two methods. You can use either **$req->input('param')** or **$req->param** based on your preference. The **$req->param** is just a shorthand notation for the **$req->input('param')**. Choose the one that you find more readable and consistent with your coding.

Comment: yes wait I am updating my answer, it is very easy to provide the default value

Comment: sorry i was delete my question cause i've read the below answer. Unfortunately you already answer it LOL. Thank you sir

Comment: `$req->param` will try to return an input first then fallback to a route parameter

Answer (score 0):

Both are used to retrieve input data from the request.

The only difference is that you can define the default value using `$req->input()`.

example :

```
$param = $req->input('param','default');
```

Comment: so basically, $req->input('param','default') means if $req->input('param') doesn't exist, it would get $req->input('default') ?

Comment: no, it means if $req->input("param") doesn't exist it will take "default" as the default value. now $param will have the value "default" instead of null value.

Comment: That was exactly what i really mean. Thank you for your answer!